# Jquery Mobile Data from WCF to List

Tags: wcf, jquery-mobile

I am new to Jquery Mobile. I am trying to load a list from web service results , below is the code when I call the web service directly can see the output but not able to view from Jquery mobile

Below are my Jquery mobile code and Web service output. Any help would be great for me.

```
var serviceURL = "http://localhost:8008/Service1/";
var employees;
$('#employeeListPage').bind('pageinit', function(event) 
{
   getEmployeeList();
});

function getEmployeeList() 
{
    $.getJSON(serviceURL, function (data) 
    {
        alert("asda")
        $('#employeeList li').remove();
        employees = data.items;
        $.each(employees, function(index, employee) 
        {
            $('#employeeList').append('<li>Vishnu.....</li>');
        });
        $('#employeeList').listview('refresh');
    });
}

<div data-role="content">
   <ul id="employeeList" data-role="listview" data-filter="true"></ul>
 </div>
```

Web Service Output

```
<ArrayOfSampleItem xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/RestWServices" 
 xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <SampleItem><Id>0</Id><StringValue>ItemName 0</StringValue></SampleItem>
 <SampleItem><Id>1</Id><StringValue>ItemName 1</StringValue></SampleItem>
 <SampleItem><Id>2</Id><StringValue>ItemName 2</StringValue></SampleItem>
 <SampleItem><Id>3</Id><StringValue>ItemName 3</StringValue></SampleItem>
 <SampleItem><Id>4</Id><StringValue>ItemName 4</StringValue></SampleItem>
 <SampleItem><Id>5</Id><StringValue>ItemName 5</StringValue></SampleItem>
 <SampleItem><Id>6</Id><StringValue>ItemName 6</StringValue></SampleItem>
 <SampleItem><Id>7</Id><StringValue>ItemName 7</StringValue></SampleItem>
 <SampleItem><Id>8</Id><StringValue>ItemName 8</StringValue></SampleItem>
 <SampleItem><Id>9</Id><StringValue>ItemName 9</StringValue></SampleItem>
</ArrayOfSampleItem>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your service returns Xml, but you call `$.getJSON`. You can either return Json from WCF, using `ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json` in the `WebGet` custom attribute of the service method or use [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) with `dataType` parameter set to "xml".